# Using jQuery Masked Input Plugin, is it possible to make the first part of a phone number optional?

Tags: jquery, forms, masking

Using this plugin : http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Is it possible to make something like this happen?

(As the user inputs the phone number...)

```
1__-___-____

18_-___-____

186-___-____

186-6__-____

186-612-____

186-612-3___

186-612-34__

186-612-345_

186-612-3456

1-866-123-4567
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not follow your final format?

```
1-866-123-4567
```

So, your code would look like this:

```
$("#phone").mask("(9)-999-999-9999");
```

Or without the bracket:

```
$("#phone").mask("9-999-999-9999");
```

See my [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qG4Qu/).

Comment: Because the user would always have to put 11 digits, even for a local phone number which only requires 10... 999-999-9999 would be a valid 10 digits local phone number and 9-999-999-9999 would be a valid 11 digits long distance phone number